# Which simple future-proof Delphi serial comms code to use?

Tags: delphi, serial-port

I've been a fan of Turbopower Async Pro for years, now taken up on SourceForge and it works very well. However, it's complex and I've never really made use of its features other than the port component. I'm updating my code for D2009 etc and am tempted to move to something simpler since I have my own wrapper around it. There are lots of port components out there but are there any recommendations here? Thanks.

Comment: There is an [AsyncPro version at Songbeamer that works with Delphi XE2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8138820/29290), which should work with Delphi 2009 as well.

Answer (score 7):

Lars Dybdahl recently blogged about the open source **TComport** component that's sprung back to life, and how Delphi 2007 and 2009 support have been added.

- Lars's blog: http://compaspascal.blogspot.com/2008/11/delphi-bigger-than-c-tcomport-history.html
- TComport home on SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at [SynaSer](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download) (towards the bottom of that page).  I have used his TCP/IP library for quite some time now and have found it extremely easy to use and extend and would expect his serial comms library to be similar.

Answer (score 1):

Is anything in Delphi really future-proof? Stick with open-source anyway - If it's on Sourceforge at least you have the source, and it won't vanish if the company that makes it goes out of the Delphi software business.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever works for you. If Turbopower Async Pro (duh, what a name) works then don’t change it. :)

Comment: As it may not be ported to D2009, he may have to change it!

Comment: And [Songbeamer has a version of AsyncPro that works with Unicode too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8138820/29290).