# Delphi XE2 TurboPower component status

Tags: delphi, turbopower, lockbox-3

The TurboPower components were among the most popular commercial component libraries and are still used by many Delphi developers as they went open source.  Instead of asking individually, I thought I'd ask a single question as to the state of XE2 compatibility for each of the components.  TurboPower Abbrevia, AsyncPro, and LockBox as the main ones.

Compatibility includes platform support: XE2 Win32, Win64, Mac OS X.  (I doubt that Async Pro would ever go Mac OS X, but perhaps XE2 Win32 at least.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Abbrevia v5.0** supports XE2.  Win64 is fully supported, OS X supports everything except the zipx decompression algorithms, MS CAB archives, and the visual controls.

[SongBeamer](http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/) has XE2 packages for **Async Pro**, but only for Win32.

**LockBox v2** on [GitHub](https://github.com/jarto/lockbox2) has been updated for Win64 and Delphi 2009-XE3 & Free Pascal support.  **LockBox v3.40** supports Win32/Win64 in XE2 and [the website](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/tiki-index.php) claims they're working on OS X/iOS support.

**Office Partner** has XE2/Win32 support in its Subversion repository.  I did that, but it was mostly merging changes posted in the forums.  I haven't tested it on Win64 and don't plan to.

**Orpheus v4.08** supports Win32/Win64.  AFAIK they aren't planning on supporting FireMonkey.

**OnGuard** hasn't been updated past Delphi 2010 yet.

**ShellShock**, **SysTools**, and **XML Partner** all have XE2 packages in their latest releases, but look like they're only Win32 versions.

**TP Essentials** hasn't been updated.

Comment: You might be interested in watching this too: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=71972

Comment: @Marcus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bystander_effect  Every one of those projects would be dead if someone hadn't taken over development.  I know Embarcadero was using Abbrevia for at least one inhouse project, and they've never contributed a patch, and indeed, they released `System.Zip` instead.  I'll be shocked if that QC is handled as anything other than "Won't Do"

Comment: Nick wrote that QC entry, I believe, while working at Embarcadero, and he maintains this sourceforge page, I believe summarizes the current turbopower projects active on Sourceforge: http://tpsfadmin.users.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Warren Nick's intentions were good, and I'm not criticizing him, but other than his blog posts and giving people commit privileges, he hasn't done anything.  That page is automatically generated by SourceForge to list all of the projects a user belongs to.  TurboPower created the tpsfadmin user and made it an admin on all of their projects, so it lists them all.  Nick just inherited the page when he took over the account.  It doesn't indicate whether a project is active or not, and almost half haven't had a single commit since they were open sourced.

Comment: For reference, just found LockBox on GitHub with recent activity: https://github.com/jarto/lockbox2

Comment: Hi Craig, your SongBeamer link is pointing to lockbox2 github.

Comment: @Erik Thanks, messed that up adding Darian's link.  Fixed now.