# trying to install lockbox 3 for Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, lockbox-3

I'm trying to download LockBox3 so I can encrypt some files.  I tried through Sourceforge and ran into all sorts of compiling difficulty such as the ANSI problem in the String Utility, $ENDIF rather than $IFEND, and others.  I then went to the http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/Grok+TurboPower+LockBox link and I see lists of files but I don't see how to ultimately make a package that I can use in the application.

I'm not interested in modifying any source - I'm just hoping to use the utility/component as-is to encrypt/decrypt file such as in the codec examples.

Comment: You do not need to build a package - the package for D2010 is already there (three clicks starting from your link)

Comment: But maybe you need a more convenient link to the same source inside your link https://code.google.com/p/tplockbox/source/browse/

Comment: See [Delphi XE2 TurboPower component status](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8138203/576719).

Comment: Thank you.  I see .pas files, .dpr files, .dproj, .res and others in various folders under svn.  I don't recognize a package within 3 clicks.  How do I locate the package by its name, where might it be, and how do I get it to my project?  Again my apologies for missing something that is evidently straightforward to the general community.

Comment: https://tplockbox.googlecode.com/svn/tags/LB%203.6.0.0%2010-Nov-2014/packages/d2010/

Comment: .dpk file is in that list ^

Comment: Thank you.  I began making some progress by downloading these files to my workstation and attempting to compile, but I am continually receiving "file not found" errors. I am very tediously working my way through that - but I'm thinking there must be an easier way to compile and build the package.  Is there a better way to do it directly?

Comment: Something makes me feel that you download this file by file. Did you ever used a Version Control System and checked out the files from there?

Comment: No I have not - therein lies the problem.  Is this a straightforward exercise?  I checked out the Git website but I didn't see specific instructions on downloading, only setting up and maintaining files.  Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a `svn client` (take 1 minute)

- 1) Download : [Standalone command-line Subversion client for Windows](https://sliksvn.com/download/)

The installer contains all command line tools (svn, svnadmin, svnsync, svnserve, svnmucc) but no application bindings nor Apache modules.

- 2) goto https://code.google.com/p/tplockbox/source/checkout
  there you see

> Command-line access
>
> Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:
>   Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
>   `svn checkout http://tplockbox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ tplockbox-read-only`

- 3) create a folder where you want to store the download
- 4) inside that folder open `windows cmd`
- 5) paste above `svn checkout ...` link to `cmd`

[image]

after <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the download starts.

[image]

Comment: this was an excellent explanation and worked wonderfully.  I am now working on installing the package.  Thank you very much.